How to calculate the thermal radiations of a seawater ball in the microwave range
I'm seeking for guidance on how to calculate the farfield spectral irradiance of the thermal radiations of an object made of a material with known complex permittivity ($\epsilon_r=\epsilon^{'}_r+j\epsilon_r^{''}$) in the GHz microwave range. The object could be for example a ball made of seawter.
I know about Planck's law. However, I cannot fathom how to calculate the emissivity in my particular case. In my case, the object has dimensions close to the wavelength of interest. I have found this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0504068), where they get an expression of the emissivity starting from the fluctuation dissipation theorem:

This case is not exactly mine since it deals with a 1D semi-infinite subspace. But I do not understand the given emissivity formula. The $\lvert r_{12} \rvert$ coefficients in the formula are Fresnels interface equations. Let's say we have a lossless material (medium 2) with a real permittivity $\epsilon_r=\epsilon_r^{'}=2$ and the other subspace (medium 1) is vacuum. The medium 2 is perfectly transparent ($\epsilon^{''}_r=0)$ and thus should not radiate anything. However, according to this emissivity formula it has a nonzero emissivity since the Fresnel coefficients moduli are less than 1. How come a transparent material emits thermal radiation?
TLDR: I'm looking for a way to predict the spectral irradiance of the thermal radiations of a ball made of a material defined by its complex permittivity and having dimensions close to the wavelength, in the microwave range. Thanks!
